# Socket Programming- How to get the server to store only numbers

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

i am writing a code for socket programming to be executed on the server side.
Now, the client basically send the data in form of a string(over TCP) . What my server code tries to do is read the string and store only the numbers in an array so that other functions can be carried out on these numbers obtained. But i exactly do not get how to implement this function.

```
/* tcpserver.c */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    int sock, connected, bytes_recieved , true = 1;  
    int n[3],i,arr[3][5];
    char send_data [1024] , recv_data[1024];       

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr,client_addr;    
    int sin_size;

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&true,sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("Setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;         
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(5001);     
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8); 

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
        perror("Unable to bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(sock, 5) == -1) {
        perror("Listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nTCPServer Waiting for client on port 5000");
    fflush(stdout);

    while(1) {  
        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        connected = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&sin_size);
        printf("\n I got a connection from (%s , %d)",
               inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
        while (1) {
            printf("\n SEND (q or Q to quit) : ");
            gets(send_data);

            if (strcmp(send_data , "q") == 0 || strcmp(send_data , "Q") == 0) {
                send(connected, send_data,strlen(send_data), 0); 
                close(connected);
                break;
            } 
            else {
                send(connected, send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);
            } 

            for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
                bytes_recieved= recv(connected,recv_data,1024,0);
                recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';

                n[i]=atoi(recv_data);     
            }

            if (strcmp(recv_data , "q") == 0 || strcmp(recv_data , "Q") == 0) {
                close(connected);
                break;
            }
            else  {
                for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
                    printf("\n RECIEVED DATA = %d \n",n[i]);
                    fflush(stdout);
                }
            }
        } /* end inner while */

        close(sock);
        return 0;
    } /* end outer while */
} /* end main */
```

Comment: It seems like you don't exactly get TCP/IP. This simply won't work even before it comes to parsing the string. I recommend you read some book first, like Network Programming by Stevens, and then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really say what the problem is, nor did you show your client code. but I suspect this is the issue in your server loop.

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    bytes_recieved= recv(connected,recv_data,1024,0);
    recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';
    n[i]=atoi(recv_data);     
}
```

First, if recv() returns 1024, you will wind up writing a '\0' at recv_data[1024]. The valid index ranges for this array is 0..1023.  You can easily fix this by declaring recv_data to be 1025 bytes long instead of 1024 at the top of this function.

But the real problem is that recv() can't be expected to return any expected length, regardless of the number of bytes that the client actually sent. (or as others will tell you: "TCP is a STREAM protocol")

This is likely what you want for your recv() loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    j=0; // j is declared as 32-bit int above
    success = ReadIntegerFromSocketStream(connected, &j);
    if (success == 0)
    {
        close(connected);
        connected = -1;
        break;
    }
    n[i] = j;
}

int ReadIntegerFromSocketStream(int sock, int* result)
{
    int ret;
    int count= 0;

    char COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT[ (sizeof(int)==4) ? 1 : -1 ];

    unsigned char data[4];

    while (bytes_received < 4)
    {
        ret = recv(sock, data+count, 4-count, 0);
        if (ret <= 0)
        {
            /* socket got closed, abort */
            return 0;
        }
        count += ret;
    }

    memcpy(&result, data, 4);

    // not shown: calling result = ntohl(result);
    // I'll let you look this function up

    return 1;
}
```